# Trying to use Jquery .load() with multiple Id Selectors with no success

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

In essence a user clicks on a movie title and both plot and cast is populated in my collapsible. It works well if I only use 1 selector for plot or cast, but not both. any ideas or examples? thanks

HTML...

```
<div data-role="main"  class="ui-content">
    <div data-role="collapsibleset">
        <div data-role="collapsible">
            <h1>Plot</h1>
            <p id="dvdinfo"></p>
        </div>

        <div data-role="collapsible">
            <h1>Cast</h1>
            <p id="dvdcast"></p>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript...

```
function getmoviepic_mobile(movietitle) {
    var Movie = $(movietitle).text();

    $('#dvdinfo','#dvdcast').load('getuser2_mobile.php', {input:Movie}); 
}
```

PHP...

```
<?php

include("includes/connection.php");

$q1 = trim($_POST['input']);
$result = mysql_query("
    SELECT 
         id, title, actors, plot, catagory, release_date, rated
    FROM ".TBL_DATA." 
    WHERE title = '".$q1."'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['plot'];
    echo $row['actors'];
}
```

Comment: Well what's the problem? Does *anything* happen? Are errors reported?

Comment: You need to provide information about the error

Comment: oh sorry...I just get blank in both cases, where if I use only one id, I get either the plot or cast. I need both to be populated.

Comment: do I need some kind of serialize jquery statement..I dont know how I can apply it this case

Comment: not impressed thats 2 questions in a row I ask and no one can help

Comment: @Nico Sorry that a group of _volunteers_ helping you for no tangible reward doesn't meet with your expectations. Plenty of questions get answered every day, maybe there's a pattern to your questions that makes them less likely to get answered. For example, the SO help docs are pretty clear about including both desired and actual behavior _in your question_ when posting about code that isn't working. Something you've neglected to do here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $x=[
        'plot'=>$row['plot'],
        'actors'=>$row['actors']
    ];
}
echo json_encode($x);
```

JS:

```
function getmoviepic_mobile(movietitle) {
    var Movie = $(movietitle).text();
    $.getJSON('getuser2_mobile.php', {input: Movie}, function(json, textStatus) {
        $('#dvdinfo').html(json.plot);
        $('#dvdcast').html(json.actors);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that !

Answer (score 0):

replace this line

```
$('#dvdinfo','#dvdcast').load('getuser2_mobile.php', {input:Movie});
```

with this one

```
$('#dvdinfo,#dvdcast').load('getuser2_mobile.php', {input:Movie});
```

Comment: that works to a certain extent in that in both collapsibles I get the plot and the cast combined.